# When deploying FastAPI app to Google Cloud App Engine receiving no module found error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, fastapi

How should I fix this error message? Code works perfectly in local with docker-compose up. Just not working on google app engine

Error Message:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'butler_app'
at _find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
at _gcd_import (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
at _call_with_frames_removed (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219)
at _find_and_load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:961)
at _find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
at _gcd_import (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
at import_module (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127)
at import_app (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py:358)
at load_wsgiapp (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:39)
at load (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:49)
at wsgi (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:67)
at load_wsgi (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:144)
at init_process (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:119)
at init_process (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py:62)
at spawn_worker (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:583)
```

Here's my DockerFile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8


COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY README.md ./
COPY setup.py ./
RUN pip install -e .

COPY ./butler_app /butler_app

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker  --threads 8 butler_app.main:app

EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: As per the error message you are receiving it seems as if App Engine is not able to find  your main.py file where the FastAPI app() variable is defined within your Dockerfile. It seems as if this line in your Dockerfile `COPY ./butler_app /butler_app` is copying to an absolute path that might conflict with the WORKDIR and therefore it can't be found (find all the correct information [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy). Notice that the image you are using is expecting [this structure](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#how-to-use).

Comment: I assume that you are deploying on App Engine Flexible with custom runtime. But please confirm if this is the case. Also what does the setup.py file is doing on your Dockerfile? You could either use the [env variables defined for the image you are using](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#environment-variables) or try to structure your project with a much simpler folder path as e.g. the one mentioned [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-dockerized-fastapi-app-to-google-cloud-platform-24f72266c7ef). I hope you find this info useful.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Actually I redefined by docker file and utilize env variables. Thanks though!

Comment: Please post the answer of the specific measures that you took in place for the community :)